# Does a Pensieve store more than memories?

Tags: harry-potter, pensieve

In *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, Harry looks into Snape's memories. He follows his father and the Marauders.

> Harry stopped in front of the desk and gazed down at his fifteen-year-old father.

He follows them on the grounds, and they sit by a tree having a conversation, far away from Snape.

> Harry looked over his shoulder yet again and saw, to his delight, that Snape had settled himself on the grass in the dense shadow of a clump of bushes. He was as deeply immersed in the OWL paper as ever, which left Harry free to sit down on the grass between the beech and the bushes and watch the foursome under the tree.

It's Snape's memories, and in this point Snape is focused on his OWL paper and I highly doubt he heard the Marauder's conversation. So why can Harry hear them? It's not part of the memory.

> "You mean...that stuff's your thoughts?" Harry said, staring at the swirling white substance in the basin.
>
> "Certainly," said Dumbledore.

So does the Pensieve have the ability to store a whole scene, even if it's not in the memory? If so, shouldn't it be used more frequently? For example:

- In *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, Fudge could've checked his memory to see how Dumbledore escaped.
- In *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, Dumbledore could've checked Viktor Krum's memory, to see who snuck behind him and killed Barty Crouch.
- Snape could've checked his memory when he heard the prophecy. He got kicked out in the middle, but Trelawney was still saying it, so Snape can just check the Pensieve through his memory, even though he didn't actually here the whole thing.

So why does the Pensieve store additional memories? And why isn't it used more?

Comment: @Laurel- no. That question asks how far you can explore a memory.  I'm asking why you can explore a memory

Answer (score 0):

There are theories that we store more memories than we can consciously recall, so even if the primary/conscious attention is elsewhere, the person remains subconsciously aware of other activity in their vicinity, and able to recall those details with the right techniques.

Hypnosis has been used to try to access witness memories ([not very reliably](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/hypnosis)); a Pensieve may simply do this better.
It will still be limited to scenes that the person the memory belongs to was able to witness, but can allow more details to be reviewed than they could describe.

In the scene described, Snape is distracted, so conscious attention isn't on the Mauraders. He's within sight and earshot of them, so in principle could have awareness of the conversation Harry sees.

Worth mentioning that even the things we think we are directly looking at are not viewed continuously like a camera would record them, so some suspension of disbelief/additional magic is required even for the focus of a memory.